# How to use AppGallery for existing android application

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

***What I currently have:***
I have a application running in Android Playstore

***What I am trying to do:***
I want to add this app in [**Huawei App Gallery**](https://huaweimobileservices.com/appgallery/)

***Questions:***

- What are the changes I need to do for  this in code, If any ?
- Are there any blogs or article for this, to check for more
  information

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about general policies for entry to an application store front, not about a specific programming issue with the application that wouldn't allow it to enter or an specific question about how the policy affects the application programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to signup for Huawei Developer Account (Free)

You don't need code changes. Refer this documentation from Huawei Developers.

[Documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/devservice/doc/30204)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options we can go for:

**OPTION 1**

Step 1: You need to create a [Huawei Developer Account](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/).

Step 2: Create a project in [console](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/console) using your project name and package name

Step 3: In console enable the services needed in your application to run.

Step 4: Declare your project SHA256 signing certificate fingerprint in the console.

Step 5: Download the agconnect-service.json file from the console.

Step 6: Write code for HMS by keeping GMS code also. Check out the below link on how to keep both GMS and HMS in same project:

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201308778868370129

**OPTION 2**

Use [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881) to quickly migrate the app to HMS Core to release it on HUAWEI AppGallery.